# The difference between to-infinitives and Ving after superlative adjectives

Tags: to-infinitive

> We can use a to-infinitive after a superlative adjective, with a meaning similar to a relative clause with who, which or that:
>
> Who was the oldest person **to compete** in the London Marathon of 2008? (Who was the oldest person who competed …?) [From Cambridge Grammar](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/comparison-adjectives-bigger-biggest-more-interesting)

Can competing be used instead of to compete here? If so, what's the difference between them?

Comment: ...who competed, ...to compete, ...competing... I don't hear any difference among the three, for a past event. For a future event, only the latter two are valid.

Comment: The marked infintive **to compete** feels more abstract to me than **competing**.